# How to enable/ disable item in f.select if another item has been selected in another f.select element

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, drop-down-menu, haml

I have two f.select elements with their own list items in a haml form.

```
%h3 Base
      = f.select :project_type, Project.types, {:disabled =>  <"project 4" (if Project.risky?)>}, required: true
     = f.select :risky, Project.risky, {:disabled =>  <"yes" (if Project.some_condition?)>}, required: true
...
```

if the `f.select :risky` is set to 'yes' I'd like the 4th option of value 'project 4' to be disabled in `f.select :project_type`, else keep it enabled/selectable. Similarly, if `f.select :project_type` has the 4th option selected, I want the `f.select :risky` dropdown list to have the `yes` option disabled

Comment: This is not related to ruby nor haml, you can't do that serverside. You need to use javascript, listen to the `change` event on the select tags and enable/disable the options with javascript.